# Было бы правильно или было бы правильным?

Tags: грамматика

"С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы правильно указывать..." или "С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы правильным указывать..."? Подскажите, как правильно и есть ли какое-то правило для таких случаев?

Answer (score 3):

> "С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы правильно указывать..." или
> "С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы правильным указывать..."?

**Правильны оба варианта.**

Из Грамматики—80:

> **§ 2413.**  <...>
>
> Во всех формах, кроме формы наст. вр., для некоторых наречий нормальна
> мена наречия на *-о* и соответствующего прилагательного в форме
> тв. п.: *Было бы излишне спорить - Было бы излишним спорить; Было бы
> напрасно думать, что... - Было бы напрасным думать, что...; Более
> самоотверженно/более самоотверженным было бы отказаться; Рекомендовать
> примирение в этом случае было/будет/было бы наивно/наивным; Связывать
> эти два поступка было бы неверно/неверным.* <…> В целом отмечается
> тенденция к расширению возможностей тв. п.; в то же время построения с
> тв. п. имеют стилистическую окраску книжности.
>
> http://rusgram.narod.ru/2405-2422.html

Несколько примеров с творительным падежом:

Ю.А. Пинчук: *…в оценках социальной борьбы народных масс того времени **было бы правильным указывать** на неясное представление ими будущих общественных отношений…* (Роль народных масс в освободительной войне…1986)

В.М. Марков: *…применительно к XVIII веку **было бы правильным противопоставлять** не словенское и русское , а архаичное…* (Формирование норм русского литературного языка XVIII века. 1994).

И.П. Распопов: *По-видимому, **было бы правильным сказать**, что...*
(Строение простого предложения в современном русском языке. 1970).

Алексей Васильевич Текучев: *...вряд ли **было бы правильным распространять** опыт самообучения таких людей на массы учащихся…* (Методика преподавания русского языка в средней школе. 1958)

Comment: Слава, спасибо за поиск. В целом результат получился _ожидаемым_. К общей норме, проиллюстрированной примером "**кататься было бы весело**" в комментарии добавлено допущение "мены наречия и прилагательного для _некоторых_ наречий"; "в то же время построения с тв. п. имеют стилистическую окраску книжности" (я дал чуть менее дипломатичное наименование этой "стилистической окраске", хотя мог бы и назвать "канцеляризмом").

Comment: Это допущение "мены" даже названо "нормой" - по всей видимости, это дань речевой практике позднего советского периода и более поздней. Таковы все примеры для выражения "было бы правильным (+ инфинитив)", находящиеся в "корпусе"; большей частью это нормативные документы и журнальная публицистика, классические литераторы в результатах не представлены. Найденных результатов с прилагательным примерно вдвое меньше тех, что я считаю стилистически безупречными.

Answer (score 2):

Есть правила на этот счёт или нет, давайте разберемся в вопросе простым способом. Что употребляется с инфинитивом в изъявительном наклонении? "**Правильно указывать**": здесь форма **наречия**, а не *прилагательного* (правильн**ое** -> было бы правильн**ым**), которое невозможно употребить и в вопросительной форме: "Указывать - это правильн**о** [а никак не "правильн**ое**"]?" Соответственно, нужный вариант в вашем случае "**было бы правильно**". Как возникает вариант прилагательного "правильн**ым**" и когда он безупречен? Очевидно, когда в исходном варианте изъявительного наклонения употребимо *прилагательное*, а оно всегда употребимо в сочетании с *существительным*. Добавим таковое в ваш вариант и получим:

> С точки зрения цифрового этикета *правильн**ое** решение* (выбор, действие,
> подход и т. п.) - указывать... (изъявительное наклонение)
>
> С точки зрения цифрового этикета *правильн**ым** решением* было бы
> указывать... (сослагательное)
>
> С точки зрения цифрового этикета *правильн**ым*** было бы *указание* на... (сослагательное)

Альтернативный вариант "было бы правильным указывать" вряд ли является грамматической ошибкой (так тоже часто говорят, и можно оправдываться, дескать опущено подразумеваемое существительное), но *стилистически* он неудачен по изложенным причинам.

Comment: Alex_ander: _Соответственно, нужный вариант в вашем случае "было бы правильно"._ === НЕ СОГЛАСЕН!!!

Comment: @slava1947 Хорошо (или вдруг "хорошим"?) было бы и аргументацию несогласия почитать :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Любопытная  задачка!  И ответы тоже интересные. Мне всегда нравится, когда автор просит помочь выбрать нужную форму, а  ему отвечают: **оба варианта правильные**, любой берите,  какой больше нравится. И что же тогда делать? Надо сосредоточиться, войти в состояние медитации – и получить ответ от подсознания (это шутка, но в каждой шутке есть доля правды).
   К тому же я полагаю, что  ничего одинакового в природе не существует. Два варианта верны **в общем случае**, а в частном и конкретном **один из них непременно лучше другого,** вот и нужны **конкретные рекомендации**. Поэтому мне тоже захотелось решить задачу.
2. Итак, согласно Грамматике  возможны обе формы. При этом следует учесть, что это верно **не для всех наречий**. Варианты отсутствуют  у целого ряда слов,  «лексически и функционально тяготеющих к предикативам».  Но наречие «правильно»  – это оценочное наречие, поэтому для него варианты возможны.  Это подтверждает и статистика, к которой надо в таких случаях обращаться **в первую очередь**.
3. **Какую форму выбирают пользователи?**
   Статистика Нацкорпуса за весь период такова: было бы правильно – 51 пример, было бы правильным –  22 примера. Также нельзя сказать, что «в целом отмечается тенденция к расширению возможностей Т. п.»,  как это утверждает Грамматика. Статистика по периодам: Было бы правильно – 34/29/8 примеров, было бы правильным –  18/17/1 пример за периоды с 1980/2000/2010 года.
   Так что не спешат авторы расширять  сферу применения Т.п. Возможно, форма «было бы правильно» **кажется им более естественной, но не для всех случаев**. А вот для каких?
4. Чтобы  определить  какую-либо **закономерность,** рассмотрим конкретный пример с похожей грамматикой: (1) **Указывать** на ошибки – (это) **правильно.**

Предложение двусоставное, инфинитив в роли подлежащего,  наречие является именной частью сказуемого.  Тире ставится при отсутствии связки согласно правилам для инфинитива, так как его синтаксическую роль бывает трудно определить.

(2) **Указывать** на ошибки  было бы **правильно**. (3) Было бы **правильно** – **указывать** на ошибки.

При наличии связки  в постановке тире необходимости нет, но при инверсии главных членов тире опять желательно поставить из-за **прямого контакта инфинитива и наречия** (тогда образуется нежелательное сочетание  «правильно указывать»).

(4) Было бы **правильным указывать** на ошибки.

А вот Т.п. решает эту проблему. Таким образом, можно предположить, что именно форма Т.п. позволяет **избежать некорректного сочетания наречия и инфинитива** в таких конструкциях, когда тире между ними нельзя поставить и пауза в устной речи отсутствует.

5. В то же время при  выборе варианта следует учитывать **структуру предложения** – например, наречие и инфинитив может разделять **произносительная пауза**, и тогда использование наречной формы допустимо, например:
   *Было бы **правильно**  // **залечь и спать** до весны, в каком тысячелетии она бы ни наступила.* [Слава Сэ. Ева (2010)]
6. Но вернемся к заданному предложению: *С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы **правильно указывать**..»*  Трудно судить по фрагменту,  но, скорее всего,  при такой структуре предложения здесь **нет даже произносительной паузы**,  а соединение наречия и инфинитива в одну фразу нежелательно. Поэтому я бы использовала Т.п.: *С точки зрения цифрового этикета было бы **правильным  указывать***…

Примеры из Нацкорпуса

(1) **Творительный падеж**

Кроме того, мне кажется, было бы правильным поставить эти вопросы на обсуждение на одном из международных собраний ученых. [Г. Горелик. 2008]

Было бы правильным усилить наблюдения и анализ в этой области, до конца разобраться в причинах… [«Вопросы статистики», 2004.06.24]

Исходя из этого, было бы правильным и справедливым вынести его на широкое всенародное обсуждение. [А. Амбарцумян. 2002]

(2)  **Наречная форма**

Было бы правильно инновационную активность бизнеса, крупных корпораций оценивать интегральным показателем активности компании на рынке интеллектуальной собственности. [Е. Каблов, 2015]

Среди действующих депутатов есть активные, инициативные люди, думаю, что было бы правильно их оставить (2011).

… с вашей стороны было бы правильно не защищать вашего Чонкина, а, наоборот, порвать с ним самым решительным образом. [В. Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975)]

Comment: Шарон, рад тому, что Вы тоже избрали бы здесь вариант с тв. падежом. Мне тоже, как и Вам, хотелось бы уйти при прочтении этого предложения от сочетания "правильно указывать". И для себя я бы выбрал именно вариант с творительным. Но настаивать на нём не стал: написал, что оба варианта возможны. Почему? Да потому, что прочитать сочетание "было бы правильно указывать" с интонацией, неправильно задающей смысл слову "правильно", русскоговорящий человек вряд ли способен. Никакой двусмысленности такой вариант не несёт.

Comment: И примеры с слитным сочетанием "было бы правильно + инфинитив" и в Нацкорпусе есть. А вот почему Вы их не заметили, а привели совсем другие примеры... P.S. Но, повторюсь: для себя я бы выбрал вариант с творительным...

Answer (score 0):

Slava, отвечаю на ваш комментарий.

Сразу хочу сказать, что подборка примеров **неслучайная** – это те предложения, в которых выбор одной из двух форм кажется мне **обоснованным**.

Вообще говоря, форма Т.п. выглядит довольно экзотично, так как она применяется для **ограниченного количества наречий**. Действительно, мы же не говорим  «было бы интересным послушать» или «было бы приятным погулять по лесу». Вероятно, Т.п. воспринимается пользователями **по-разному:** одни его вообще не замечают, другие считают две формы одинаковыми. Более тонкое восприятие – это различение их на **интуитивном уровне.**

Но если форма появилась в языке, то она фиксируется  в грамматических справочниках и должна как-то объясняться, но **объяснений я не вижу**. А вот **логикам** Т.п. не нравится, ведь падеж – это  категория существительного. Поэтому надо говорить так:  «правильным решением было бы». **Существительное в форме Т.п. действительно присутствует**, но незримо. А прилагательное, вероятно, субстантивировалось при отсутствии существительного.

Остается понять, **почему эта форма  вообще появилась** – интересно, кто-нибудь высказывался по этому поводу? Интересны и перспективы Т.п. Вряд ли современное поколение отличается особой тонкостью слуха, поэтому вопрос остается открытым.

**И еще несколько слов об интонации** приведенного предложения и о моем решении использовать Т.п.: «*С точки зрения цифрового этикета // было бы **правильным** указывать*…»
Нам кажется, что интонация – это выбор читающего, но это не совсем так. **Интонация задается структурой предложения,** а мы ее обычно только считываем, хотя варианты возможны. Но в данном случае **мы уже делаем паузу** после обстоятельственного оборота, поэтому нам приходится  читать в одну фразу **«правильно указывать».** И даже если мы верно  понимаем смысл сказанного, все равно некорректное сочетание **неприятно воспринимается** на слух.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что граница между допустимостью и недопустимостью прилагательного в тв. п. для подмены  тех самых "некоторых наречий" проходит по контексту: если в построенную фразу можно _буквально вернуть опускаемое существительное_ (правильным -> делом правильным - такая замена не всегда возможна), не покорежив её, то прилагательное уместно; в противном же случае возникает ощущение _грамматической_ ошибки. Возможно, именно этим обстоятельством ограничивается и сам круг подменяемых ("некоторых") наречий.

Comment: Я думаю, что конкретного текста это не касается - "правильное решение" можно подставить в любое предложение. А вот круг заменяемых наречий действительно  определяется сочетаемостью с каким-то обобщенным пропущенным существительным.  Например, для "было бы интересно узнать" такое обобщенное существительное сложно подобрать.